# NetBeans Glassfish hangs at "In-place deployment at..."

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, glassfish, freeze

I've been working quiet some time on this project without any issues.
Recently, i tried to start the application but nothing happened.

Litteraly, nothing happened.

NetBeans starts the glassfish server, and starts deploying the application. But that's it. It just hangs there, deploying the project until eternity.

I don't get any errors, the glassfish server just starts up succesfully, the application deploys succesfully (i guess?)

So sorry, i dont have any error message to show...

This issue only occurs on this particular project. I've tried other projects and they work fine.

So, I tried to revert my project to an older version of the application, where it worked just fine. But even after this revert, nothing happened.

I've reinstalled NetBeans (8.2), together with GlassFish 4.1.1, still no succes.

Other group members working on this same project dont have this issue. They are able to work on this project without any issues.

[This is a picture of the processes running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnrGO.png)

This is my application's output:

```
Deploying on GlassFish Server 4.1.1
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1.1
GlassFish Server 4.1.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\target\S44VolksBank-0.1
```

This is the glassfish server output:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
mei 08, 2017 3:13:49 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
mei 08, 2017 3:13:49 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
mei 08, 2017 3:13:49 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
mei 08, 2017 3:13:49 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/GlassFish/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@7cf38c0 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 25ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Warning:   Unable to load class org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster
Info:   Loading application [target] at [/target]
Info:   Loading application target done in 3.518 ms
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (13.973ms), startup services(4.118ms), total(18.091ms)
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 17ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://WillemLT:8686/jndi/rmi://WillemLT:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@78830d9a as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@3fae596.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context ''
Info:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Info:   Loading application __admingui done in 3.790 ms
```

And finally my IDE log:

```
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 910.5MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 2.4MB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=23 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=4 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=12231 total loaded=12234 unloaded 3
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 8,497,946,624
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 892 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 40 binary roots took: 503 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testest\src\test\java took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\webapp took: 426 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testest\src\main\resources took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testest\src\main\java took: 180 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\java took: 96 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\resources took: 92 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java took: 63 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testest\src\test\resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testest\src\main\webapp took: 45 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 10 source roots took: 904 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@5ed2c03c, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=3926, version=1, file=null
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]: Unpaired license 00000008 without any module.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 250 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 1 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\webapp took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\java took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\resources took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 4 source roots took: 1 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 151 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 1 binary roots took: 59 ms
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (nu.validator.source.LocationRecorder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\webapp took: 8,877 ms (New or modified files: 64, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\java took: 1,871 ms (New or modified files: 48, Deleted files: 3) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\resources took: 94 ms (New or modified files: 1, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java took: 568 ms (New or modified files: 11, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 4 source roots took: 11,410 ms (New or modified files: 124, Deleted files: 3) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 18 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\NetBeans\NetBeans 8.2\webcommon\jsstubs\reststubs.zip took: 61 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\NetBeans\NetBeans 8.2\webcommon\jsstubs\domstubs.zip took: 44 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\java took: 32 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\resources took: 18 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java took: 23 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\NetBeans\NetBeans 8.2\webcommon\jsstubs\corestubs.zip took: 39 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 6 source roots took: 217 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.bugtracking.BugtrackingManager]: Loading stored repositories took 337 millis.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.semantic.SemanticHighlighter@617cf3b5 : class org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.semantic.SemanticHighlighter ignored cancel for 95 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: CancelableTaskWrapper[task: org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsTask@5b636577, phase: RESOLVED, priority: 500] : class org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceAccessor$CancelableTaskWrapper ignored cancel for 72 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: CancelableTaskWrapper[task: org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.spiimpl.hints.HintsTask@5198ee46, phase: RESOLVED, priority: 500] : class org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceAccessor$CancelableTaskWrapper ignored cancel for 63 ms.
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@7843cd4, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=1944, version=71, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@2544252b[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\SearchTest.java@6f647245:32c476ce]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@764e0553, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=2320, version=78, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@362b1420[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\TaskTest.java@b3173d86:1256bb55]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@3b58c6ce, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=9059, version=259, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@5d43d791[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\database\FilterValueRepoTest.java@f7918e55:246c412c]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@1396fedb, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=6060, version=173, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@38592f89[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\database\FunctionRepoTest.java@f46cf7d2:1376e702]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@655e315f, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=3533, version=117, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@1d9376fc[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\database\TaskRepoTest.java@ea2214a7:445a0b7d]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@50e9f6de, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=2831, version=91, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@1dac9dc7[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\LogInTest.java@ab0067e6:3c962a0a]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@2ffa3817, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=3392, version=118, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@23cbf57f[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\JobOfferTest.java@532df68c:2f250bb5]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@1f21d9b0, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=2178, version=85, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@3e7c01cb[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\FunctionTest.java@1bfc3db5:597f39aa]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@d2325ca, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=1926, version=79, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@1d19a8eb[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\Models\AccountTest.java@30755e22:1ea20fd1]
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove java.beans.PropertyChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument.removePropertyChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.editor.NbEditorDocument@59c06d1c, mimeType='text/x-java', kitClass=null, length=1627, version=80, file=org.netbeans.modules.java.JavaDataObject@2e6ba21e[C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java\database\DatabaseTest.java@938fcf23:7a8f17ba]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@fff7e04[MultiFileObject@6da756e7[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 24 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\webapp took: 163 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\java took: 2,717 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\main\resources took: 53 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\Willem\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PTS4\S44Volksbank\S44VolksBank\src\test\java took: 129 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 4 source roots took: 3,062 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [glassfish]: GlassFish configuration file C:\GlassFish\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml was modified, updating server configuration.
```

Comment: So i've come a little closer to the solution. Apperently, this only happens at projects i pull from SourceTree. I cannot create, delete modify classes from these projects (Netbeans deadlocks) either. Once i move these projects to another folder, everything starts to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution after 3 days of searching....

For some reason, i had to install Git on my PC.

Weird, because it used to work without any problems without git installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and got an easier solution, just change the browser you are executing your web application with. I've changed it from Google chrome to IDE's default server (also Google Chrome) and the application immediately executed.

[image: click here to see where to change it]